# Focus on timepicker instead of modal window

Tags: html, angular, typescript, timepicker

My modal window is blocking my time picker on Angular

Component.ts

```
  open() {
    const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open();

    amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe(time => {
      console.log(time);
    });
  }

  // Triggering the modal window
    createApplication(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {centered: true, size: 'lg'});
    }
```

Modal html

```
  <ng-template #create let-modal>
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Job Application</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form #createApplicationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createApplicationForm.form.valid && createForm(createApplicationForm)" >
              <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control" id="preferredContactDate" name="preferredContactDate"
                        [(ngModel)]="newApplicationFormDateModel" ngbDatepicker #preferredContactDate="ngbDatepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-append">

                        //Open time picker here
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="open()"
                                type="button"></button>
                        </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- Submit button -->
                    <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="Create" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
      </div>

  </ng-template>
```

However, when i do this, the time picker gets blocked by the modal.

Any ideas?

[image]

Stackbliz for timepicker - https://stackblitz.com/edit/amazing-timepicker-example

Referenced to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazing-time-picker

Modal: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Update based on answer:

```
<div class="time-picker">
  <input atp-time-picker value="19:00"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.time-picker {
    position:absolute;
    z-index : 99999999;
  }

  .my-custom-class{
    z-index: 900;
}
```

I also tried inline style as well

```
<input style= "z-index: 99999999;" atp-time-picker value="19:00"/>
```

Comment: For modal window what have you used?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples updated link to modal

Comment: give your modal a lower z-index than the timer has. I can see the timer has an z-index of 1000 and the modal has a zindex of 1050. so try giving the modal z-index 900 for example.

Comment: Hi there, may i know where to change the modal z index?

Comment: Yes, you can give it a custom class, example here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#options

and specify the z-index in this class

Comment: This is a common issue the Angular and Bootstrap combination of modals. As the time-picker is an Angular component as per the official documentation:
`Retain your Angular project a time picker.

A visual time picker for angular 2+ projects. You can use this timepicker with Angular 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 and Angular Material.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get the bootstrap's z-index dynamically and increment it with some arbitrary number and set to the time-picket something like below:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
      const zIndex = 1045 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
      // this zIndex can be assigned to the time-picker
      $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
      }, 0);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a custom class for the modal to overwrite the z-index.

example:

in your js/ts:

```
this.modalService.open(content, {backdropClass: 'my-custom-class'});
```

css:

```
.my-custom-class{
z-index: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to the one mentioned here : https://github.com/owsolutions/amazing-time-picker/issues/129

The proposed solution, as think win win explained, was to increase the timepicker's z-index :

```
time-picker {
  position:absolute;
  z-index : 99999999;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it without the leading dot ? `time-picker` as opposed to `.time-picker`